# Insert an image into SQL using VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, image

How can I insert an image from my computer into SQL using VB 2012?

Consider that the image name is **XYZ**, located in "My Documents". the image is to be inserted into a field named **ABC**.

Comment: normally only image names are stored on the db. The image is stored on the server

Comment: Try something first and then show us what you have tried. And from there the SO community will provide you with suggestions and/or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a binary field for that. I found this on the internet.

```
CREATE TABLE Images(image varbinary(max))
INSERT INTO Images(image)
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\My Documents\Image1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

Give this a try, or change it to fit your tables. Notice that the C:\ is the disk of the sql server.

This is however the SQL CODE not in VB. But you can simply put this statement into a New SqlCommand

I found the code here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1867959.aspx

EDIT

This article here shows a example of how it can be done in vb.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9068625-ec19-44c9-9650-816e6f12af72/vb-net-codessaving-image-direct-to-sql-table?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: sir, what i wanted was how do i do this using VB2012 as a front end?

Comment: Have you looked at this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409419/varbinary-and-image-conversion

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a binary column in the table first, as has been suggested by Kay Nelson, however I imagine the file to store is not on the server, so to store it in the table, you need to open a filestream and write it to the server.
Have a look at [How to save a PDF file in a SQL Server column using vb.net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262087/how-to-save-a-pdf-file-in-a-sql-server-column-using-vb-net-code) - it's in C# but it's very easy to translate to VB.NET.